# How to create an array of abstract classes

Tags: java, arrays, abstract-class

I have an abstract class Cell:

```
public abstract class Cell{...}
```

I also have to other classes like:

```
public class BigCell extends Cell{...}
```

and

```
public class SmallCell extends Cell{...}
```

and I want to create an array(10x10) that has in the diagonal(i=j) cells of Cell class, up of the diagonal type BigCell cells and down SmallCell cells I wrote this code but is wrong because I can't create the diagonal(i=j) because is type Cell:

```
public void initializeTable(){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                if(i == j){
                    table[i][j] = new Cell();
                }else if(i > j){
                    table[i][j] = new SmallCell();
                }else{
                    table[i][j] = new BigCell();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create my table?

Comment: `Cell[][] table = ...`. Also, `new Cell()` won't compile because `Cell` is `abstract`. Just don't make `Cell` an `abstract` class.

Comment: If you want to create instances of `Cell` it apparently shouldn't be abstract...

Comment: Your subject says, "how to create an array..." but your code example does _not_ create an array.  The array must already exist before initializeTable() is called.  The initializeTable() method attempts to populate the array with references to new Cell objects, but as Philip has already mentioned, you are not allowed to `new Cell()` because that's what `abstract` means.  It means, this class definition is incomplete:  You may instantiate its children, but you may not instantiate this class itself.

Comment: You should read about inheritance and abstract classes.

Comment: yes i have a table private Cell table[][]. So if i delete the if(i=j){...} that creates the diagonal my function should be right?

Comment: if you remove if(i=j){...}, then you will have `null` reference on diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class can not be instantiated with `new`. That's the whole point of the `abstract` keyword. [The official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) reads:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

When you want to create instances of a class which are exactly that class and none of its subclasses, then do not declare it as abstract.

When you would like to keep your `Cell` class abstract for some reason, you could create an additional `class SimpleCell extends Cell` (or another appropriate name) and use this to represent the diagonals in your table.

Answer (score 1):

`public abstract class Cell{...}` cannot have it's own instance, because of the `abstract` modifier.  When you writing `public abstract class MyClass` you're telling, that you're creating a type, that will by extended by other classes, but pure object of `Cell` are not allowed. More about it [in this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352109/java-abstract-modifier).

Solution:

1. remove abstract modifier (code works right after doing it, if there ware no methods defined with abstract modifier).
2. create other type like `public class MiddleCell extends Cell`. and in code `table[i][j] = new MiddleCell();`

P.S. if it has to be an abstract class, I would recommend renaming it to `AbstractCell`

Comment: Solution 3: `new Cell(){ /* Implement abstract */ }`

Comment: that's true ;) However in this particular problem i think, it is better to use either 1 or 2.